# ICU DateFormatSymbols::getMonths()

Tags: c++, icu

I'm working on a project that makes use of ICU's libraries to handle date information in various languages. I use the following code in a function:

```
UErrorCode uec;
Locale locale(language); // e.g with language = "en"
DateFormatSymbols symbs( locale, uec );
int32_t count;
auto months = symbs.getMonths(count);
for( int32_t i = 0 ; i < count; ++i ){
  // some code handling month names, no ICU;
}
// more code that does not use ICU
```

The value of `count` is supposed to be set by the `getMonths()` method as the number of months obtained, e.g. 12 when the language is English.

The problem is, when I call the same function multiple times, sometimes `count` is 12 and sometimes it is 0, seemingly unpredictably. What is worse, the same code behaves differently on my colleagues' PCs and changes behavior when I add lines of code that have nothing to do with `symbs`, such as for example creating a `UnicodeString` somewhere within the function.

I suspect that something is off with the initialization of `DateFormatSymbols` or the locale, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what. Can anyone please tell me why this happens and possibly how to fix it so that I always get the expected number of months in `count`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize `uec`:

`UErrorCode uec;`

and then you need to check its result

`DateFormatSymbols symbs( locale, uec );
if (U_FAILURE(uec)) {
   … // handle error … 
}`

see [error handling](http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-Error-Handling)